# Libogg compiled with standalone toolchain (generated by NDK script) tries to load itself from incorrect file - libogg.so.0 instead of libogg.so

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, shared-libraries, ogg

I'm trying to add libogg to my android NDK project.

I'm using project template that comes with SDL library.

I'm on Windows, so all following scripts were executed under MSYS, a linux terminal emulator.

First, I generated a standalone toolchain.

```
android-ndk/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-12 --system=windows-x86_64 --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 --install-dir=Y:/gcc_android_androideabi-4.9_api12/
```

Then I built the library.

```
make clean
configure CC="/y/gcc_android_androideabi-4.9_api12/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc" LIBS="-lgnustl_shared" CFLAGS="-mthumb" --host=arm-linux-androideabi
make
```

Then I copied resulting `libogg.so` to my project folder and added following to my `jni/src/Android.mk`:

```
...

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ogg-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../prebuilt-libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libogg.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

...

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := ... ogg-prebuilt ...

...
```

Similar code works fine for another libraries that I use.

`ndk-build` successfully finds my libraries and adds them to the `.apk`.

The problem arises when I call `System.loadLibrary("ogg");` at runtime. Dynamic linker gives me error message saying something like

> Can't find library "libogg.so.0".

I'm sure that my library loading code is ok because it works for other libraries that I have.

Error from the dynamic linker is interesting because `make` not just generated single `libogg.so`. It generated 3 completely same files with different names: `libogg.so`, `libogg.so.0` and `libogg.so.0.8.2`.

I tried to replace `libogg.so` with `libogg.so.0` and adjusted `Android.mk` properly, but NDK build script yelled at me, saying that prebuilt shared libraries must have `.so` extension. I tried to just copy `libogg.so.0` to `libs/` folder, but NDK build script ignored it when building `.apk`.

Then I opened `libogg.so` in a hex editor and searched for `libogg`. I found only one occurence: `libogg.so.0[NUL]`. I replaced `.0` with 2 `[NUL]`s, so it became `libogg.so[NUL][NUL][NUL]` and now library loads perfectly.

---

I can reproduce this error with all toolchains I use: `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.9`, `i686-linux-android-gcc-4.9` and `mipsel-linux-android-gcc-4.9`. They all are generated using similar scripts.

The error persists if I rename `libogg.so.0` or `libogg.so.0.8.2` to `libogg.so` and use it instead of original one. As I said, all three files have same content.

**While I can make a `sed` script to automatically fix library name in `.so` files when necessary, I wonder if there is a better solution to this problem.**

Maybe I have to add some flags to `configure`?

Answer (score 1):

My slightly less hacky fix for this is to remove the version information from the build system of libogg.

In the directory where you have the libogg source code, open the file `src/Makefile.am` and change this line:

```
libogg_la_LDFLAGS = -no-undefined -version-info @LIB_CURRENT@:@LIB_REVISION@:@LIB_AGE@
```

to

```
libogg_la_LDFLAGS = -avoid-version
```

If you don't have automake installed then you can change the generated Makefile after running `./configure`. Find the `libogg_la_LDFLAGS` and make a similar change to the one detailed above. On Linux a sed one-liner like this does the job:

```
sed -i 's/^libogg_la_LDFLAGS.*/libogg_la_LDFLAGS = -avoid-version/g' src/Makefile
```